# Is this partition problem NP-complete?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

> Problem description:
> You are given an integer array Inventories representing the ribbon
> inventories, where Inventories[i] represents the length of the ith
> ribbon, and an array of orders. Each order in orders is an array of
> integers, representing the ribbons needed with certain lengths for
> that order. For example, if order = [1,2], then that means this order
> need a ribbon with length 1 and a ribbon with length 2. You may cut
> any of the ribbons in the inventory into any number of segments of
> positive integer lengths, or perform no cuts at all. However, you
> cannot combine two ribbons in the inventory to form a longer ribbon
> and fullfil an order. Each segment/ribbon in the inventory cannot be
> reused. The question is, what is the maximum number of orders that can
> be fulfilled?

Example 1:
Input: Inventories = [1,8,7], orders = [[1, 2], [4, 3, 6]]
Output: 2
Explanation: First cut inventories[1] into [2,6], then the inventory become [1, 7, 2, 6]. Use inventories[0] and inventories[2] for the first order. The rest of the inventories are [7,6], then cut the ribbon with the length of 7 into 4 and 3 to fulfill the second order. So in total 2 orders are fulfilled.

Example 2:
Input: Inventories = [1,2,3], orders = [[3, 3], [4]]
Output: 0
Explanation:
None of the orders can be fulfilled. Notice we cannot combine inventories[0] and inventories[1] for orders[0].

Example 3:
Input: Inventories = [3], orders = [[2]]
Output: 1
Explanation: Cut the ribbon into 2 and 1, and use the first segment for that order.

More than interested if anyone could outline a short proof of the NP-completeness, maybe there is some dynamic programming or memorization solution.

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Please [edit] your question to comply with our standards.  This will also help others with a similar question find this page via search.

Comment: @kallikles, of course, you know this problem is not NP-complete.

Comment: Try a greedy approach.